# Excessively high 'access' rates in the NFS client

Tags: nfs, nfsclient

Our server shows excessively high 'access' rates in the NFS clients, which makes the NFS slow.
Could you provide any suggestions on what we should investigate and how to resolve it? I'm attaching the nfsstat output at the NFS client, /etc/fstab of the client, and /etc/exports of the server.

```
root@g0:~# nfsstat 
Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
6498703    0          6499048 

Client nfs v4:
null             read             write            commit           open             
5         0%     163950    2%     911       0%     1         0%     4803      0%     
open_conf        open_noat        open_dgrd        close            setattr          
0         0%     2590      0%     0         0%     3919      0%     500       0%     
fsinfo           renew            setclntid        confirm          lock             
15        0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     
lockt            locku            access           getattr          lookup           
0         0%     0         0%     6304625  97%     7592      0%     5179      0%     
lookup_root      remove           rename           link             symlink          
5         0%     976       0%     397       0%     23        0%     0         0%     
create           pathconf         statfs           readlink         readdir          
125       0%     10        0%     27        0%     118       0%     399       0%     
server_caps      delegreturn      getacl           setacl           fs_locations     
25        0%     2345      0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     
rel_lkowner      secinfo          fsid_present     exchange_id      create_session   
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     11        0%     16        0%     
destroy_session  sequence         get_lease_time   reclaim_comp     layoutget        
7         0%     128       0%     7         0%     9         0%     0         0%     
getdevinfo       layoutcommit     layoutreturn     secinfo_no       test_stateid     
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     5         0%     0         0%     
free_stateid     getdevicelist    bind_conn_to_ses destroy_clientid seek             
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     
allocate         deallocate       layoutstats      clone            
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     1         0%
```

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#               to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#

/home      10.10.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_all_squash,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/root      10.10.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_all_squash,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/proj      10.10.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_all_squash,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/workspace 10.10.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_all_squash,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# 
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-q5DcFjbshxTDlCuacLnsd3IFvJQOfS4SODLBIwBPX8cZdUgBMwL90aXZJUMgf1iz / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2a559d14-d24f-4e83-9467-032a1bd81887 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
10.10.10.1:/home        /home           nfs     defaults                0       0
10.10.10.1:/root        /root           nfs     defaults                0       0
10.10.10.1:/proj        /proj           nfs     defaults                0       0
10.10.10.1:/workspace   /workspace      nfs     lookupcache=none        0       0
10.10.10.2:/cabinet     /cabinet        nfs     defaults        0       0
```

Two peculiar behaviors were observed:

1. root shows higher NFS performance than users (might be reasonable because 'access' indicates the number of permission checks)
2. The NFS performance for users is faster on the first login after reboot, and drops after the second login.

Comment: That `lookupcache=none` looks like the immediate suspect. Remove it and see if it helps.